# Регулярное выражение и цикл

Tags: perl

есть регулярка 
https://regex101.com/r/GD5G8f/2

Вот код

```
my @events = ("CALL", "DBMSSQL");
local $" = "|";
foreach($txt =~ /(^\d\d:\d\d\.\d+[-]\d+,(?|@events)(?:.*?)(?|Method[^,]+|Context=([^'][^,]+)|Context='([^']+)).*?$)/gm) {
    say "=======";
    say $1;
   # ParsLine($txt);
}
```

в консоле одно и тоже выводит, а нужно что бы каждый из match. Что-то с флагами напутал?

Comment: ну так `my @q = $txt =~ /(^\d\d:\d\d\.\d+[-]\d+,(?|@events)(?:.*?)(?|Method[^,]+|Context=([^'][^,]+)|Context='([^']+)).*?$)/gm;`

Comment: Блин, я ж в теле цикла $1 использую, а надо $_

Comment: а как тут "спасибо" ставить? Или комментарию нельзя?

Comment: просто удали вопрос